# How to handle "#" needed for Backbone.js with SASS

Tags: backbone.js, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to use SASS with compass to create image spirits. However, I am also using backbone.js, so my url's look like: `http://localhost/social/#/dashboard`

So when I use `@include arrow-sprite($name);` it gives me a url like: `http://localhost/social/#/images/sidebar_buttons/arrow-sa2b2afd371.png`

Which chrome inspector gives me this error: `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html`

If I go and remove the "#" from the url, the image loads fine. My config.rb looks like:

```
http_path = "/social/"
project_path = "C:/wamp/social"
css_dir = "styles/css"
sass_dir = "styles/sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Comment: Try enabling relative assets in your config.rb:  `relative_assets = true`

Comment: Or switch to absolute URLs or use the path from the root.

Comment: @cimmanon add your answer so I can give you credit! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable relative assets in your config.rb:

```
relative_assets = true
```